# Content Script - Empty Response from Regular Axios Call in Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, axios, content-script

When making an axios call in my google content script that's being executed on http://example.com, the response status is a 200 and I'd expect a json response but instead the data is an empty string like this:

```
response = {data: "", status: 200, statusText: "", headers: {…}, config: {…}, …}
```

content.bundle.js

```
const url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1";
var config = {
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
    },
}
axios.get(url, config).then((response) => {
    debugger;
    console.log(response);
});
```

manifest.json

```
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": ["content.bundle.js"],
      "css": ["content-styles.css"]

    }
  ],
```

If you're interested in the headers

```
Request URL: https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 200 
Remote Address: 104.24.99.239:443
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
access-control-allow-credentials: true
Provisional headers are shown
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Referer: http://example.com/
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.80 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
```

I'm able to get around the issue by sending a message to the background script, ideally could avoid this extra step.

Thoughts? Happy to provide more info if needed.

Thanks

Comment: Chrome disallows cross-origin fetches in content scripts now. Do it in your background script as shown in the [official CORB explainer](https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/extension-content-script-fetches).